# Find only CR files (mac only)

Tags: linux, carriage-return

How can I grep only files with CR line return (excluding CRLF and LF)?

With `grep -rl $'\r' *` I find both CRLF and CR, while with `grep -rl $'\n' *` I find all LF.

Maybe I can do an exclusion?

Comment: Well, probably `grep -rl $'\r[^\n]' *` ...

Comment: Do you want to find <<files with at least one occurrence of a CR not followed by LF>>, or do you want to find <<files with at least one occurrence of a CR not followed by LF that also have zero occurrences of LF>>?

Comment: @arkascha it says "grep: brackets ([ ]) not balanced"

Comment: @MarkPlotnick it would be nice to have both, but I think I need the first (files with at least one occurrence of a CR not followed by LF)

Comment: This most likely is an effect of the shell argument expansion, not of the expression itself. Try double escaping: `grep -rl $'\\r[^\\n]' .`...

Comment: It works, thanks @arkascha! Post it as solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to exclude matches of an additional `\n` found immediately after a `\r` to filter out those:

```
$> grep -rl $'\\r[^\\n]'
```

Note the double `\\`, apparently the usual backslash notation has to be escaped to "survive" the shell interpretation before getting fed into the actual `grep` command.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could be of help :-)